# Moving to the next page after splash screen

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

Dears,
At first am so new to programming and flutter.
I bought an app code and I did the re-skin, but am facing an issue with the splash screen

the code was like this:

```
import 'package:cirilla/constants/assets.dart';
import 'package:cirilla/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ui/painter/zoom_painter.dart';

import 'widgets/zoom_animation.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key, this.color, this.loading}) : super(key: key);

  final Color? color;
  final bool? loading;

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Size size = Size.zero;
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late ZoomAnimation _animation;
  AnimationStatus _status = AnimationStatus.forward;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2500),
      vsync: this,
    )
      ..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {
        setState(() {
          _status = status;
        });
      })
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    _animation = ZoomAnimation(_controller);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    setState(() {
      size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    });
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant SplashScreen oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (!widget.loading! && _controller.status != AnimationStatus.forward) {
      _controller.forward();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_status == AnimationStatus.completed) return Container();

    return Stack(children: [
      SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: ZoomPainter(color: widget.color!, zoomSize: _animation.zoomSize.value * size.width),
    ),
  ),
  Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: itemPaddingExtraLarge),
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Opacity(
        opacity: _animation.textOpacity.value,
        child: Image.asset(Assets.logo, width: 200, height: 200, fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
      ),
    ),
  )
]);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

'''

and was just fine I turned it to this

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:rive/rive.dart';
 
 class SimpleAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
   const SimpleAnimation({Key? key, this.loading}) : super(key: key);
   final bool? loading;

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return const Scaffold(
       body: Center(
         child: RiveAnimation.asset('assets/splash/splash.riv',
           fit: BoxFit.cover)
       ),
     );
   }

 }
```

All I need is just to make it go to the next screen after 5 seconds, I tried many things but nothing sometimes I get a black screen after the splash screen I created with RIVE and most the time it just stuck after playing.

just to note, the following code is in home.dart

```
     return Stack(
  children: [
    widget.store!.data == null ? const Empty() : buildOnBoarding(context),
    SplashScreen(loading: widget.store!.loading, color: Colors.white),
  ],
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Create method like this.Here `future. delayed` solve our problem to show animation 5 seconds as splash screen

```
setdata(BuildContext context) async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
    SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WelcomeScreen()),
      );
    });

  });
}
```

Splash Screen may like this

```
class SimpleAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  const SimpleAnimation({Key? key, this.loading}) : super(key: key);
  final bool? loading;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setdata(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
          child: RiveAnimation.network(
            'https://cdn.rive.app/animations/vehicles.riv',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After splash page
`welcome.dart`(You must wrap the widget with `Scaffold` widget.other wise you get ***black screen***

```
class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const WelcomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text(
            "HOME PAGE",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**SampleCode:**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:rive/rive.dart';
    
    void main() {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    
      runApp(MaterialApp(home: SimpleAnimation()));
    }
    
    setdata(BuildContext context) async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
    SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WelcomeScreen()),
      );
    });

  });
}
    
    class SimpleAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
      const SimpleAnimation({Key? key, this.loading}) : super(key: key);
      final bool? loading;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        setdata(context);
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              child: RiveAnimation.network(
                'https://cdn.rive.app/animations/vehicles.riv',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      const WelcomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Text(
                "HOME PAGE",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help, but how if I want it to move to a page home.dart?

Comment: `Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => home()),
      );` .Home must be widget class